# Classes of javax.faces.bean are gonna be deprecated - a notification issued by NetBeans IDE 8.0

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jsf-2.2, netbeans-8

I'm using NetBeans IDE [8.0](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0/). The IDE issues a notification  as shown in the following snap shot.

> Classes of javax.faces.bean are gonna be deprecated

[image]

Is there any reason for this notification, may be the classes from the specified package are going to be deprecated shortly?

My application uses,

- Mojarra 2.2.6
- PrimeFaces 4.0
- PrimeFaces Extension 1.1.0
- GlassFish Server 4.0
- OmniFaces 1.6.3

and other related components.

Comment: The reason is simply that is going to be deprecated. CDI, which is more advanced than `javax.faces.bean` will be used for the JSF framework in the future.

Comment: The grammar of the error is intriguing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since JavaEE 7, JSF favors CDI over Managed bean. That's why `javax.faces.bean` will eventually be deprecated but it's gonna be slowwwww.

**FYI**:

- [You should not have any other @ManagedBean beside @Named.](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/04/you-should-not-have-any-other.html)